# If I hire workers for my field, does their work count for my cultivate, fertilize, sow, and harvest achievements?

Tags: farming-simulator-2017

I was awarded $1,000,000 in game currency for collecting all 100 gold nuggets so I have some extra money laying around.  If I were to hire workers, does their work count towards my achievements that are for different farming tasks? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: As in sowing/harvesting so many acres of field?

Comment: Yes, I can link the achievements I'm referring to

Comment: I can attest that they did count towards achievements in FS2015 on xb1. I rarely drove the harvester but have an achievement for harvesting more than 100 hectares. I drove my water / fertilizer tractor 99% of the time, and had bots for the rest of the vehicles.

Comment: I dont see why it shouldnt count towards your acheivements. It always has done so with previous versions.

Comment: I do not know if workers count, but I do know that working for other farmers counts towards it.